# Differential Equations for Physics

Tags: reference-request

My teacher recently gave me a big 150-paged syllabus for the International Physics Olympiad because he is confident in my ability to score in the top 5 nationally. Howeverr, I'm really young so I have to catch up on a lot of mathematics. the first dozen of pages of the syllabus describe some of the differential equation in Physics, for example radioactive decay. I, however do not completely understand these equations to be honest. My question is, is there a (short) text book or site which teaches the differential calculus needed for Physics?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's probably hard to beat:

http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/

and it's free. Of course there are many other online resources like this site. My advice would be to pick a book and ask questions here as you get stuck.

Comment: Wow, it has an entir MIT textbook on differential and integral calculus! Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep. By the way, I teach calculus almost every semester and I have tons of stuff at www.supermath.info on calculus and some physics.